# Showing uniform convergence of $(1-t^n)^{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following sequence of functions: $$h_n(t) = (1-t^n)^{2^n}, \,\,\, t \in [0, 1], n \in \mathbb{N}$$ and I have shown that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \textrm{for }t \in [0, \frac{1}{2}), \\ 0 & \textrm{for }t \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1], \\ \frac{1}{e} & \textrm{for }t = \frac{1}{2} \end{array}\right.$$ by looking at the logarithm. I now need to show that this converges uniformly on open intervals that don't contain $\frac{1}{2}$, but I'm not really sure how to go about it. It looks like I should use the Weierstrass M-test, but I can't really see the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0\le a<1/2$. The function $1-(1-t^n)^{2^n}$ is positive and increasing. Then
$$
0\le1-(1-t^n)^{2^n}\le 1-(1-a^n)^{2^n},\quad 0\le t\le a.
$$
This shows that $h_n$ converges uniformly to $1$ on $[0,a]$ (and on closed intervals that do not contain $1/2$.) But the convergence is not uniform on $[0,1/2)$. If $0<\epsilon<1/2$ then
$$
0<t_n=\bigl(1-(1-\epsilon)^{2^{-n}}\bigr)^{1/n}<1/2
$$
and
$$
1-h_n(t_n)=\epsilon>0.
$$

The case of intervals $[b,1]$ with $1/2<b<1$ is treated similarly.